# Which CSS do I need to mark a piece of text as highlighted?

Tags: html, css, highlight

In my web app, I want to highlight a piece of text so that it looks like somebody has painted it with a certain color. The Medium app uses this effect, too.

(I would like to show an image of this effect here, but stackoverflow does not allow me to post it because I do not have enough reputation points, yet.)

What kind of CSS and/or HTML markup do I need to achieve this?

As a side note: My app is written with React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the semantic [`<mark>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag for this:

```html
<p>This is some <mark>marked text</mark>.</p>
```

You can then style it any way you want using CSS:

```css
mark {
  background-color: HotPink;
}
```

```html
<p>This is additional <mark>marked text</mark>.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter if the application is written in React on any other framework. You can always define a CSS for basic html tag, such as <mark>.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:

- Highlight using the HTML `<mark>` tag

```html
Here is an example of <mark>highlighted text</mark> using the &lt;mark&gt; tag.
```

- Highlight text with only HTML code

```html
<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">Yellow text.</span>
```

- Highlight text with CSS & HTML

```css
body { background-color:green; }
.highlight { background-color:#FFFF00; }
p { background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

```html
<span class="highlight">Highlighted Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter if the application is written in React on any other framework. You can always define a CSS for basic html tag, such as  as @Salaman suggested.

You can use the example that @Salman provided, but I would suggest a small modification.

```css
mark.hotPink {
  background-color: HotPink;
}
```

```html
<p>Do not forget to check out our <mark class="hotPink">hot new offer</mark> today.</p>

<p>Also, you can check out our <mark>standard offers as well</mark>.</p>
```

You can write a CSS for  tag but you probably don't want to do it for every mark tag (because you don't know if some other part of the system might be affected by this. **The best (and the safest) way to do this is to create a custom class (i.e. class="hotPink" and assign it to your mark.**

Hope this helps, all best! :)